# No supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

Given this in my datacontext:

```
public class EventsForUserID
{
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public string eventIdentifier { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventOpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventCloseDate { get; set; }
    public bool eventDisabled { get; set; }
    public EventsForUserID() {}
    public EventsForUserID(string pEventName, int pEventID, string pEventIdentifier, DateTime pEventOpenDate, DateTime pEventCloseDate, bool pEventDisabled)
    {
        this.eventName = pEventName;
        this.eventID = pEventID;
        this.eventIdentifier = pEventIdentifier;
        this.eventOpenDate = pEventOpenDate;
        this.eventCloseDate = pEventCloseDate;
        this.eventDisabled = pEventDisabled;
    }
}
public List<EventsForUserID> GetEventsForUserID(string userID, bool excludeDisabled)
{
    var e = 
        from ex in this.Exhibitors
            join ev in this.Events on ex.EventID equals ev.EventID
            where ex.UserID.ToString() == userID
            select new EventsForUserID (
                ev.EventName, 
                ev.EventID, 
                ev.EventID + "[::]" + ex.ExhibitorID + "[::]" + ex.AccountDisabled + "[::]" + ev.EventDisabled, 
                ev.OpenDate.Value, 
                ev.CloseDate.Value,
                ev.EventDisabled
            );
    if (excludeDisabled) {
        e = from ev in e
            where ev.eventDisabled != true
            select ev;
    }
    return e.ToList();
}
```

I get the error:
   The member 'LeadsDataContext+EventsForUserID.eventDisabled' has no supported translation to SQL.

on the return.ToList() line.

I've tried all sorts....AsQueryable() etc

I figure it because EventsForUserID is not a true sql table, but then I thought LINQ was for performing queries over many type of object.

Am I missing a cast of some sort.

Many thanks, N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot mix linq-to-objects and linq-to-sql freely in the same query. If you are running the query as a linq-to-sql query, everything must be translated to sql.

Try to split your code into two queries. The first one should retrieve the relevant data from the database using linq-to-sql. The second uses linq-to-objects to do the final filtering/manipulation of data.

Comment: Thanks fro the pointer. This has fixed it: if (excludeDisabled) {
            var etemp = from ev in e.ToList()
                where ev.eventDisabled != true
                select ev;
            e = etemp.AsQueryable();
        }